# How to "graceful terminate" a smart contract from the "rococo-contracts-rpc.polkadot.io" chain?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, pallet-contracts, cargo, cargo-contract

In theory we could use this command:

cargo contract remove --execute --code-hash '******' --url 'wss://rococo-contracts-rpc.polkadot.io' --suri 'seeds'

But in order to do that we have first to [terminate](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/fn.terminate_contract.html#) the smart contract that was uploaded and instantiated.

How to do this in a "graceful way" ?

Note:For instance in Ethereum there is a horrendous thing called "[selfdestruct](https://ethereum-blockchain-developer.com/022-pausing-destroying-smart-contracts/04-destroy-smart-contracts/)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions would be to have per default as "best practices" in every smart-contract created a function called "destructor" together with a "beneficiary account".

> ```
>     #[ink(message, payable)]
>     pub fn destructor(&self)  -> Result<(), Error> {
>         let caller = self.env().caller();
>         if caller == self.beneficiary_account_id {
>             self.env().terminate_contract(self.beneficiary_account_id);
>         } else {
>             return Err(Error::InvalidCaller);
>         }
>     }
> ```

Would be nice to hear other points of view of this approach.

Cheers,

Comment: By the way there is a good example [here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/tree/main/contract-terminate)